# How to enable hourly granularity for cost and usage data in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli, cost-management

I am trying to call get-cost-and-usage api of AWS to generate hourly report. But, i am getting an error around enabling an opt-in only feature.

```
aws ce get-cost-and-usage --time-period '{"Start": "2020-06-10T00:00:00Z", "End": "2020-06-15T00:00:00Z"}' --granularity 'HOURLY' --metrics "AmortizedCost" "BlendedCost" "NetAmortizedCost" "NetUnblendedCost" "NormalizedUsageAmount" "UnblendedCost" "UsageQuantity" --group-by Type=DIMENSION,Key=SERVICE
```

Error Message:

> An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetCostAndUsage operation: Hourly data granularity is an opt-in only feature. You can be enable this feature from the PAYER account’s Cost Explorer Settings page.

I don't see any settings page to enable this feature. Is there any way to enable this feature, via console or cli?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is mentioned in many documentation links about.

```
Hourly data granularity is an opt-in only feature.
```

And when we execute the CE API, it also throws the error.

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetCostAndUsage operation: Hourly data granularity is an opt-in only feature. You can be enable this feature from the PAYER account’s Cost Explorer Settings page.
```

But no screenshot or detailed information is provided any where.
I am attaching the screenshot, How to enable "Hourly and Resource Level Data" e.g opt-in for Hourly data granularity.

I am using consolidated Billing account, so this setting is needed in main Payer's account.

[image]

Few things more to consider about this settings:

> Allow all accounts to access hourly and resource-level information for
> the past 14 days. Resource-level information is only available for
> your Amazon EC2 service usage.
>
> Please note that it can take up to 24 hours for your data to become
> available, and a cost of $0.01 per 1,000 UsageRecords-month will be
> incurred as a result of storing and accessing your hourly- and
> resource-level information. A UsageRecord is defined as one line of
> usage. For example, one EC2 instance running for 24 hours will
> generate 24 distinct UsageRecords at the hourly granularity.

After this settings, you can run CE API Calls. e.g

```
aws ce get-cost-and-usage --time-period Start="2020-07-07T10:00:00Z",End="2020-07-07T11:00:00Z" --granularity HOURLY --metrics "BlendedCost" --group-by Type=DIMENSION,Key=SERVICE Type=TAG,Key=Environment
```

One thing to note is that, in case of HOURLY, the time format must be in yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ format.

Answer (score 3):

You can opt-in to hourly granularity on the AWS Cost Explorer Settings page.

If you have a single account, this can be done inside the account.

If your account is part of an AWS Organization, it must be done from the Organization’s payer account.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a link to get to this settings page or a screenshot to show where the link is? I don't see it anywhere in the Cost Explorer Page or Billing Preferences page.

Comment: For anyone who is looking for a link, here's how to get to the settings page:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/home#/settings

Answer (score 1):

You can enable hourly reporting here

https://console.aws.amazon.com/cost-management/home?#/settings

[image]

The feature was released Nov 13, 2019 and you can find the costs associated here

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-cost-explorer-supports-hourly-resource-level-granularity/